# how to add button while click any one of other appear two different pics using frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29lI.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfftu.jpg)how to add to button using Html, CSS, JavaScript and bootstrap?
suppose that one is food and other is juices.
Now by click food, 3 different food images appears and when clicking juice 3 different juices images appear.

I was expecting this I don't know why this link appear bcz I uploaded two pics.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**This how you can display your products**

```
  //This is an array of objects that contains your menu items
  let products = [
   {id:0, name:"Burger", price:150, img:"assets/images/burger.jpg"type:"foods"},
   {id:1, name:"pizza", price:150, img:"assets/images/pizza.jpg", type:"foods"},
   {id:2, name:"fries", price:150, img:"assets/images/fries.jpg", type:"foods"},
   {id:3, name:"strawberry", price:150, img:"assets/images/strawberry.jpg", type:"juices"},
   {id:4, name:"apple", price:150, img:"assets/images/apple.jpg",type:"juices"},
   {id:5, name:"orange", price:150, img:"assets/images/orange.jpg"type:"juices"}
  ]
  
  //Declare an array that will contain items
  //depending on the user choice(FOODS or JUICES)
  let filtered = []

  //This is the input where the user will choose either Foods or juices
  let input = document.querySelectorAll(".ma__filter__item")

  
  
  // Here you will filter the products depending on the user choice 
        if(input.value == "foods"){
            var results = products.filter(prod => (prod.type ==="foods"))
            //putting the filtered products in the filtered array
            filtered = [...results] 
        }
        else if(input.value == "juices"){
            var results = products.filter(prod => (prod.type === "juices"))
            //putting the filtered products in the filtered array
            filtered = [...results] 
        }
    })

  for(let i=0 ; i < filtered.length ; ++i){
    console.log(filtered[i])
    //checkout the function below
    newproduct(filtered[i])
  }

  //This is the div where you display your items
  let grid = document.querySelector("#ma__grid");
  //you have to empty the div before appending the filtered products
  grid.innerHTML = "" ;


//This function will create a div
//and add the filtered products data into it
//then append it to the grid div
function newproduct(prod){
  let newProd = document.createElement("div");
  newProd.className = "ma__grid__item";
  newProd.innerHTML =  `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top crd_img" src=${prod.img} alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body container">
            <div class="row ma__prod__name">
                <h2>${prod.name}<h2>
            </div>      
            <div class="row ma__prod__details">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur llitia. Quo</p>
            </div>  
            <div class="row ma__prod__name text-center">
                <p class="col-lg-12">price : ${prod.price}$</p>     
            </div>   
            <div class="row ma__prod__name d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button name ="${prod.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ma__prod__btn ma__prod__btn1">Add To Cart</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ma__prod__btn ma__prod__btn2">More Details</button>
            </div>                        
        </div>
    </div>  `;

  grid.appendChild(newProd);
}
```

Comment: We'd prefer that you didn't write code for questions that provide none. It promotes poor quality questions. Please see [ask] and [answer].